# File tranfer between two machines using QTcpSocket

Tags: qt, sockets

My class link has all the funcionts for file transfer between two machines. Here is the code and the order in which it is called.

Machine A sends a Request to send a file to Machine B. If B accepts it creates a TCPServer:

```
quint16 Link::createServerToReceiveFile(QString savefile, qint64 size){

    // Initializing control variables.
    saveFile = savefile;
    numberOfBytesToReceive = size;
    bytesWritten = 0;

    // Initializing server for Download
    transferServer = new QTcpServer();
    transferServer->listen(QHostAddress::Any);
    connect(transferServer,SIGNAL(newConnection()),this,SLOT(on_transferServerHasNewConnection()));
    return transferServer->serverPort();
}
```

Then Machine A uses the server port to create socket for the transfer:

```
void Link::createTransferSocket(quint32 ipnumber, quint16 TCPport, QString file2Transfer){
    fileToTransfer = file2Transfer;
    transferSocket = new QTcpSocket();
    transferSocket->connectToHost(QHostAddress(ipnumber),TCPport);
    connect(transferSocket,SIGNAL(connected()),this,SLOT(on_transferSocketConnected()));
    connect(transferSocket,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(on_readyDataFromTransfer()));
    connect(transferSocket,SIGNAL(disconnected()),this,SLOT(on_transferSocketDisconnected()));

    qWarning() << "Created transfer socket on sender";

}
```

This will eventually give the newConnection signal to Machine B's TCPServer:

```
void Link::on_transferServerHasNewConnection(){
    transferSocket = transferServer->nextPendingConnection();
    connect(transferSocket,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(on_readyDataFromTransfer()));    
    connect(transferSocket,SIGNAL(disconnected()),this,SLOT(on_transferSocketDisconnected()));
    qWarning() << "Created transfer socket on receiver";
    printSocketInfo();
}
```

Once the connection is done on B, A receives the connected signal and the transfer can start like this:

```
void Link::on_transferSocketConnected(){

    qWarning() << "Now there is a connection so the sender is sending the info";
    printSocketInfo();

    QFileInfo info(fileToTransfer);
    if (info.size() > 0){

        qint64 bytesSent = 0;
        qint64 dataWritten;
        QFile input(fileToTransfer);
        QByteArray buffer;

        qWarning() << "Sending data for file" << fileToTransfer << "Bytes:" << info.size()  << "Status" << transferSocket->state();

        if (input.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)){
            while (bytesSent < info.size()){

                buffer = input.read(TRANSFER_BUFFER_SIZE);

                // Adding the header to the data block
                //buffer.prepend(header.toUtf8());

                if (buffer.size() > 0){

                    dataWritten = transferSocket->write(buffer);

                    if (dataWritten != buffer.size()){
                        input.close();
                        transferError =  "There was an error transfering the file. " + transferSocket->errorString()  + " . Aborting";
                        break;
                    }
                    bytesSent = bytesSent + dataWritten;
                    //qWarning() << "The number of bytes written is" << bytesSent << "out of" << info.size();
                    qint32 update = bytesSent*100/info.size();
                    emit(updateTransferStatus(update,transferID));

                }
                else{
                    transferError =  "Error reading from file";
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
        else{
            transferError = "Could not open file " + fileToTransfer + " for reading";
        }

        // Disconnecting the socket and deleting the socket. Also making sure that no transfer is now underway.
        qWarning() << "Disconnecting after having supposedly finished. Transfer error is" << transferError << "Socket error" << transferSocket->error()
                   << "y el normal" << socket->error() << "state" << transferSocket->state();
        transferID = -1;
        transferSocket->disconnectFromHost();
        transferSocket->deleteLater();
        input.close();

    }
    else{
        transferError = "File " + fileToTransfer + " could not be found. Aborting transfer";
    }
}
```

Every time A writes to it's socket B should get the readyRead() signal and save the received data to a file like this:

```
void Link::on_readyDataFromTransfer(){

    qWarning() << "Aca toy";

    QByteArray buffer;
    QFile output(saveFile);

    if (output.open(QIODevice::Append)){
        buffer.append(socket->readAll());
        output.write(buffer);
        bytesWritten = bytesWritten + buffer.size();
    }

    output.close();

    qWarning() << "Received" << bytesWritten  << "of the file" << saveFile;

    emit(updateTransferStatus(bytesWritten*100/numberOfBytesToReceive,transferID));

    // When all the bytes were received the transfer mode is finished.
    if (bytesWritten >= numberOfBytesToReceive){
        transferID = -1;
    }

}
```

The problem is that the last function is never called and I cannot detect any error neither in the socket values (IP's and ports) and every debug message is written except the on_readyDataFromTransfer() messages. This slot is just never called I can't figure out why. Also since this falls outside my actual code, I have no idea how to debug it, either.

Anyone see anything wrong?

Comment: Are you sure data is written? You write the error messages on the server side to `transferError`, do you look into this string? Maybe just write it to `qDebug` or `qWarning` in each case for testing.

Comment: Don't know how to make sure that the data is written. When I write the data I make all of the checks and none of them seem to show any errors. You can see those in my code.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see the line were `transferError` is written to `qWarning`.

Comment: Yes, all it gives me is unknown error